# How to check if a record doesn't exist in another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, caml-query

I have listA
      and another ListB

When i a user views an item in ListB there is a custom button that the user clicks.
Now when the user clicks the button i insert some rows into ListA which are:
1) The ID of the item in ListB 
2) The username of the user.

So listA looks like this.

```
ID username Title
13 userB    Boy
15 userA    Trouble2
15 userA    Trouble2
```

In listB

```
ID Title
13 Boy
14 Girl
15 Trouble2
```

Now you can see this means that user A has clicked the item 15 twice which is Title Trouble2.(I mean ID 15 has been inserted twice see above)

So i would like to show a view like this(When userA logs in he sees the below)

```
ID username
13 Yes
14 No
15 Yes
```

Any ideas and thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure that your examples match your question exactly. Do you want to avoid creating duplicates in List A or simply create a view which doesn't show them? Are you writing server-side or client-side code? Can you provide an example of your code so far?

Comment: Marc what i'm simply after is if the userA logs in - I use the username and the ID  to check each row and if it already exist "YES" if not "NO"
Do you know what i mean?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you simply want to eliminate duplicates in your display of ListA for each user. (I still don't think your examples are consistent with what you are saying, exactly.) So you need to filter for the current user, and group on the ID column.

To do this, I'd use a Data View Web Part. Filtering for the current user is fairly straighforward. To eliminate the duplicates, I usually use the ddwrt:NameChanged function ([Eliminating Duplicates in Data View Web Parts](http://sympmarc.com/2007/10/23/eliminating-duplicates-in-data-view-web-parts/)), though there is also some XSL magic you can use ([XSL Alternative to Eliminating Duplicates Using ddwrt:NameChanged](http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/21/xsl-alternative-to-eliminating-duplicates-using-ddwrtnamechanged/)).